# How To Disable the Input bar in dialogflow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have a FAQ chatbot in CX. I want the customer to choose from my available options only and not allowing them to type a question. How can I disable the input bar? Please provide details and thank you

Comment: What are you using as your input source for end user interactions?  Are you interacting with a browser or something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create a Conversation profile, then enable a smart reply. You must have completed one of the following in order to create a conversation profile:

-To implement FAQ Assist or Article Suggestion you must create a knowledge base with documents in it.

-To implement Smart Reply you must train a Smart Reply model and manage its allowlist.

https://cloud.google.com/agent-assist/docs/conversation-profile